# Is there any way that I can do format matching within a column in powerBI? ( something similar Fuzzy)

Tags: powerbi

I have a column look like as below.

DK060
DK705
DK715
dk681
dk724
Dk716
Dk 685 (there is a space after Dk).

This is obviously due to human error. Is there any way that I can ensure the format is correct based on the specified format which is two uppercase DK followed by three digits?

Or Am I being too ambitious!!??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the power query editor. Select advance editor and paste this 2 steps

```
#"Uppercase" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Source",{{"Column", Text.Upper, type text}}),

#"Replace Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Uppercase"," ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column"})
```

Note: be sure to replace the "Source" statement into the Uppercase sentence for your previuos step name if needed.

So you will have something like this:
[image]

This is the expected result:

[image]